# wordpress gallery with link on caption text

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am having a problem, I am trying to create a gallery in wordpress where clicking on the caption text will redirect me to the attachment page while clicking on the thumbnails will open the picture/gallery itself.
Here is something similiar http://themes.themolitor.com/wphud/category/portfolio/

Comment: How are you creating this gallery? Please, add the relevant code.

Comment: I created a new page and used the upload/insert button. I uploaded all the pictures and everything works fine except that the description of every picture is visible only if I select attachment page in the link url field. Here is the page :http://businesskortet.dk/?page_id=58. Some of the pictures have caption already. Is there anyway to make create a link there? on the caption text?